# Having visual studio/resharper run tests from referenced assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, xunit.net

I have a library full of unit tests (xunit) in which I can inject some elements used by those tests.

I'd like to have a project running all those tests with mocked endpoints and another with real (live, acceptance environment) endpoints.

But when I create a new project and reference the unit tests library, Resharper (or VS2015) doesn't offer me to run any test.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper doesn't support that. You'd have to either a) derive from all of the test classes, so they live in the assembly you're testing, or b) use an external UI to run the assembly that you've got tests.

Comment: Is there a pattern or(/and) reflexion usage, which can allow me to work around this?